# About %in% return value in R

Tags: r

I have two sets(a and b). I try to use %in% to choose all values in a, that are also in b.

The set a is read from text file using the following code:

```
a <- read.table("filename.txt")
names(a) <- c("time","A")
```

the output from this table read is like this

```
a <- data.frame(time = seq(0,20,0.2), A = seq(1,20,0.0333))
```

The set b is shown as the following format,

```
b <- data.frame(x = seq(1,20,0.2))
```

To achieve the match purpose, I need to use %in% like this

```
a <- subset(a, time %in% b$x)
```

Now an issue come out, some values in the a set are also in the b set.However, the return subset does not contain these value because they are considered no-match one.

I do not understand why this happen and how to fix this issue. Would you please give some suggestions to fix this problem?

Thanks

Hong

Comment: `b$x[2]==a$time[7]` is `FALSE`; `all.equal(b$x[2], a$time[7])` is `TRUE`.

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks for your response. I have one more question to ask. I would like to get all items of A for the matched case (including those incorrect displayed one). How should I write the code for this? Regards

Comment: Your current code will work if you can convert `a$time` and `b$x` to integers because integers have exact binary representations. For example: `a$time <- as.integer(a$time*10); b$x <- as.integer(b$x*10); subset(a, time %in% b$x)`.